# Maximum call stack size exceeded at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyError

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am developing an app that was working fine but now I am seeing this error that says "Maximum call stack size exceeded at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyError", which I don't have any idea about it.

I don't know which code snippet to share here to I am sharing my app.module.ts here

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouteReuseStrategy} from '@angular/router';

import {IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy} from '@ionic/angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BarcodeScanner} from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
import {AuthHttpRequestInterceptor} from './services/auth-http-request.interceptor';
import {AuthGuard} from './services/auth.guard';
import {LoginGuard} from './login/login.guard';
import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';
import {NativeGeocoder} from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ng2-tooltip-directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: '',
            libraries: ['places']
        }),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        TooltipModule
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        BarcodeScanner,
        {
            provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
            useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthHttpRequestInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
        AuthGuard,
        LoginGuard,
        NativeGeocoder,
        Geolocation
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Please help…

I am attaching a link for the error screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/10e8giz